# Where can I download a Flash CS3 30 day trial for Mac OS X?

Tags: adobe-cs3

Pretty much what the question says, I'm a poor man and I need to use Flash for 30 days!

- It needs to be CS3 because I've already had CS4 and CS5 on this computer.

When I'm done with this I promise I'll save up for some actual Flash. - Hey atleast I'm not a pirate. ;D

Answer (score 1):

It seems as the official channels do not have it for download.  Maybe someone has one out there they can send you.  Otherwise your option might be picking up a used copy somewhere. You might just be out of options in this case. With CS5 out, I am sure you can find some decently priced cs3 or cs4 sets.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Ajax Animator](http://osflash.org/ajaxanimator) to see if it meets your needs for authoring Flash content.

Answer (score -2):

[Here.](https://www.adobe.com/cfusion/tdrc/index.cfm?product=flash&promoid=EBYEX)  It's CS5 since that's the current version.  The CS3 trial has been pulled.

CS3 has been pulled.  All the pages that the trials linked to are gone.  You will need to either use a diff system or buy it.

Comment: I needs CS3! D:

Comment: See the edit.  You are SOL on getting a legit CS3 trial.

Comment: So near, but so far...
http://www.webcitation.org/5UaAoIatk

Comment: @pelms - ...Except the free trial page links to the current adobe page, which is a free trial of CS5 just like I linked.

Comment: @JNK. Sorry, wasn't referring to your answer - I meant to post the comment under the question.

Comment: @pelms - No biggie!  We both agree there isn't much he can do to get CS3!